# Recylerview in fragment doesnt populate with items

Tags: android-recyclerview, firebaseui

Sorry for this noob questons, but I am starting to learn Firebase UI and 2 days in a row I am stuck with populating a RecyclerView in a fragment.
I tried to move my code around in onViewCreated , onCreateView methods but I think that is not the problem, in log it just throws one error:

```
2020-02-18 15:08:26.730 4467-4467/com.social.voteup E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Double checked everything is linking with the xml file.
Here is my code:

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```

On View Created method

mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.posts_recyclerview);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.refreshLayout);

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

setupAdapter();

// Refresh Action on Swipe Refresh Layout
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> mAdapter.refresh());
```

I use the adapter inside the fragment as shown here:

```
 private void setupAdapter() {

        // Init Paging Configuration
        PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPrefetchDistance(2)
                .setPageSize(10)
                .build();

        // Init Adapter Configuration
        FirestorePagingOptions<Post> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<Post>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .setQuery(mQuery, config, Post.class)
                .build();

        // Instantiate Paging Adapter
        mAdapter = new FirestorePagingAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(options) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_post, parent, false);
                return new PostViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostViewHolder viewHolder, int i, @NonNull Post post) {
                // Bind to ViewHolder
                viewHolder.bind(post);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {
                super.onError(e);
                Log.e("MainActivity", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
            }

            protected void onLoadingStateChanged(@NonNull LoadingState state) {
                switch (state) {
                    case LOADING_INITIAL:
                    case LOADING_MORE:
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                        break;

                    case LOADED:
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        break;

                    case ERROR:

                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        break;

                    case FINISHED:
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        break;
                }
            }

        };

        // Finally Set the Adapter to mRecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
```

Here is the full source file on pastebin:https://pastebin.com/YkzKRuUD

Comment: did you found any solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code in the On View Created method.

You have created an adapter but you haven't attached the adapter to the recyclerView

```
mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.posts_recyclerview); 
mSwipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.refreshLayout);

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new setupAdapter());

// Refresh Action on Swipe Refresh Layout
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> mAdapter.refresh());
```

Comment: I think i have attached it inside the setupadapter method       
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);